# force redirect non www url to www

Tags: wordpress, web-config

I'm going straight to the point here.
I actually install a wordpress site on a windows server.
however, when I visit the site on my browser using `"sample.com.ph"` it shows me `The connection has timed out` however when I visit the `"www.sample.com.ph"` it work just fine.

Here's my web.config file.
I am really new to this so please bear with me.
what I want is to force it to redirect to a `www.`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
      <rule name="WordPress: http://www.sample.com.ph" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
      </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you check your httaccess file? regenrate it.

Comment: #Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj what do you mean sir?... I thought htaccess won't work in windows server...